# Why Doesn't Chrome Display SVG's with <use> and Filter="url(#id)" Attributes?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

## Background

I have a set of SVG icons that all have drop shadows. To make this work in Chrome, I can't just use `filter:drop-shadow`. I have to use `filter:url(#drop-shadow)`, and define the drop shadow in my `<defs>` section.

I also have multiple instances of these icons on the page (they are filetype icons in a list of files), so I am using `<use>` to keep my page DRY.

## Code

**Exernal SVG File**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow">
            <feGaussianBlur xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/>
            ..... more filter lines, shortened for brevity
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="download-pdf">
        <path filter="url(#drop-shadow)" d="" fill="">...</path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="download-zip">
        ..... another icon
    </symbol>
    ... more icons
</svg>
```

**Inline SVG on the Page**

```
<svg>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="URL_OF_EXTERNAL_SVG"></use>
</svg>
```

See minimal working example here: http://h.andymercer.net/chrome-svg-bug/

## Problem

The problem is that Chrome isn't finding the `#drop-shadow` link, and so is breaking the icons. Firefox, conversely, displays the icons perfectly.

**Firefox:**

[image]

**Chrome:**

[image]

If you notice, the Chrome screenshot DOES show some portion of the icon. It is displaying the portions that don't use the drop shadow filter.

I can't figure out why this is, because the drop shadow is in the `<defs>` that is on the same page as the `<symbol>`.

## Question

Is there something I am missing, or is this a Chrome bug?

## Edit

Per comments, I was asked for a MCVE. I hadn't done that because the problem inherently requires external URLs, which is typically frowned upon here. However, to demonstrate the problem, take a look at this:

http://h.andymercer.net/chrome-svg-bug/

In Firefox, you can see the icon. In Chrome, it is blank.

Comment: An MCVE would be useful here.  Are you sure the id "drop-shadow" is unique on the page?

Comment: I have added an MCVE, Paul. And to Robert, I saw that bug but I don't think it applies. The filter is being applied to the symbol in the same URL as the filter exists.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, `<defs>` must be located inside the same `<svg>`.
In your case:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow">
            <feGaussianBlur xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="download-pdf">
        <path filter="url(#drop-shadow)" d="" fill="">...</path>
    </symbol>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#download-pdf"></use>
</svg>
```

Conforming to modern browsers capabilities, it's easier and cleaner to create different external svg files, one for each icon, then embed them using `<object>` or `<img>` tags.

`<object>` lets javascript access and modify SVG code via DOM, while `<img>` embed SVGs denying DOM access to them. So, in your case using `<img>` should be a better choice.